# some part of the image becoming invisible while using it on html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am talking about the image in the second section of [link](https://www.thealphateam.digital/demos/pando/control-tower.php) on this HTML page.
and here is the [link](https://www.thealphateam.digital/demos/pando/assets/images/2sec.svg) of the original image.

when you inspect the HTML page you can see, I am using the same image as the link given, and still, the hand in the image is not showing, I tried to do resizing and everything on inspect so that the hand in the image become visible but not working. I thought it is an issue of z-index but I checked everything z-index is fine, the border part of the hand is visible.

I just saw with different Mac and safari browser the image is showing up with hand but in my system, Linux, and chrome browser the image is showing up without the hand.

```
<div class="col-lg-4  is-animated">
                        
                            <img src="assets/images/2sec.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        
                    </div>
```

Comment: Did you set the css ```object-fit``` property?

Comment: @Bryce yes tried, nothing is happening, you can also try by going to the link and using inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Progu, Thanks for your answer, your answer was working but I started facing another problem with my javascript code, scrolling stopped working when I used an object tag to display image...

so I searched for more alternatives to display images apart from an image tag, and I found the Iframe method, it worked awesomely. but still, if someone knows why this was happening and can display it with the image tag can answer.

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%"
   src="assets/images/2sec.svg" name="imgbox" id="imgbox">
   <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a try using `<object>` tag:

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.thealphateam.digital/demos/pando/assets/images/2sec.svg">
```

Comment: ok, I will try now... thanks bro it is working now... can you elaborate your answer why it was not working properly with the image tag but working with the object tag...

Comment: when I saw it working on safari, I thought it was browser related issue.

Comment: this alternative approach is working, the image is properly visible on all browsers. I also saw what object does it but To embed a picture, it is better to use the <img> tag. after using object tag I am facing a different bug, scrolling is not working, I am using javascript for section based scrolling. after going to second section when I used object then it is not scrolling to section 3

Comment: the svg is embeded with another image (the hand), when using `img` tag, Chrome refuses to load it due to potential security problem, another option to open the svg file copy the entire `<svg>...</svg>` into your html page.

Answer (score 0):

Change the inline style style margin-left value.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="assets/images/2sec.svg" name="imgbox" id="imgbox" style="margin-left: 256px;">
```

And also the svg width="100%" and height="auto"

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 540 471" fill="none">
```